# How can I swap a token across different liquidity pools in a single transaction?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

im pretty new to solidity, and i was wondering how you can 1 ERC token by another across different liquidity pools.

Example:

I have 1 DAI and I change it for eth in the ETH-DAI Uniswap pool
then I swap ETH by SUSHI in the SUHSI-ETH Sushiswap pool

so the tx looks like this
swap 1 dai for x eth
swap x eth for y sushi

I guess you cant do it directly and you need to deploy a smart contract that interacts with both contracts (Uniswap ETH-DAI  and Sushiswap SUSHI-ETH) and then you interact with your deployed smart contract.
Does this have a particular name? I saw that it exist something called atomic swaps but I guess its not the same

Comment: I don't think the question makes any reference to different chains/side-chains/layers. It just concerns different liquidity pools in different AMMs on the same chain.

Comment: As @RichardHorrocks pointed, i was talking about the same chain. 
here is a sample transaction of what I want to achieve:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x97bb4ef33132389f3742724d89889b4c9c5f618ebd6c91020c4fed4f6af16831

Comment: @user71155 tx was constructed in the smart contract.

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk exactly! Thats what i want to achieve, from a smart contract create a function that takes an input amount, a path and talks to all the different liquidity pools in that path. For example, I input 1 BNB and I give two addresses, the BNB-CAKE LP address and the CAKE - BUSD LP address (it can be from another DEX, so I cant use their native router SC), the contract then needs to swap in a single transaction (really important) BNB for CAKE and then CAKE for BUSD.

Comment: @user71155, so, do that, what kind of issue do you have:)

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk the issue is that im a noob af and I don't have a clue on how to interact with multiple contracts at the same time, so idk if this kind of operation was a specific name so I can look further how to do it. Basically the problem is that I'm lost

Comment: @user71155 https://blog.infura.io/build-a-flash-loan-arbitrage-bot-on-infura-part-ii/
Here is the example with the smart contract which triggers swap between two contracts at the same time (Sushiswap and Uniswap). Nothing in particular just a regular smart contract.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, but take a look at [1inch](http://1inch.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find an example of such a smart contract.
https://blog.infura.io/build-a-flash-loan-arbitrage-bot-on-infura-part-ii/

Nothing unusual here. Just do a call to different smart contracts in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

By using the routers of both of the DEX, you'll use their swapping functions in a single contract called in one function.

NOTE: The router addresses should already be approved on the tokens you want to swap

```
   function multiSwap(uint256 deadline, uint256 amountOutMinUniswap) 
   external 
   payable {
   uint256 amountOutMinBancor = 1;
   uint256 amountOutMinSushiSwap = 1;

_tradeOnBancor(msg.value, amountOutMinBancor);
_tradeOnSushi(IERC20(BNT).balanceOf(address(this)), amountOutMinSushiSwap, deadline);
_tradeOnUniswap(IERC20(INJ).balanceOf(address(this)), amountOutMinUniswap, deadline);
```

}

This is how the transaction will be executed for three swaps, every swap will have its own function which will handle the swap on that DEX for you

This is how the trade function will look like

```
    function _tradeOnUniswap(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, 
    uint256 deadline) private {
    address tokenIn = INJ;
    address tokenOut = DAI;
    uint24 fee = 3000;
   address recipient = msg.sender;
   uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams(
    tokenIn,
    tokenOut,
    fee,
    recipient,
    deadline,
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96
);

uniswapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
uniswapRouter.refundETH();

// refund leftover ETH to user
(bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
require(success, "refund failed");
```

}